# Extreme periodic performance drops only in specific games, CPU temperature shoots up rapidly for no apparent reason

Tags: performance, gpu, throttling, cpu-temperature, cpu-throttling

Can somebody please help me understand why these massive performance spikes are happening?

https://youtu.be/v2P6i-WWP_0

This only affects specific games like Battlefield 2042 and The Division 2. Running Prime95 for a few minutes also produces these periodic drops in performance, so this most likely is coming from the CPU.

https://youtu.be/sFZFzhnPR78?t=333

I don't understand what is happening here though. The temperature only rises very slowly for the first 5 minutes, and even looks to stabilize at roughly 55°C. But then it suddenly spikes to 85°C in a fraction of second for no apparent reason, accompanied by a huge power draw. I assume that causes the throttling a few seconds later, even though the temperature doesn't seem to rise any further towards the the 90 °C threshold. The temperature then drops back down rapidly and the process repeats in short intervals, just like it does in the Battlefield 2042 example.

What could be causing this? I already swapped the CPU for a Ryzen 1600X to see if my 5900X is broken, but it shows the exact same behavior. Also swapped mainboard, memory and power supply, updated UEFI firmware, reinstalled windows, nothing makes any difference.

System specs:

- Ryzen 9 5900X
- Mushkin Redline Ridgeback G2 32GB DDR4-3600
- MSI RTX 2070
- Patriot P210 512GB
- MSI B450M-A Pro Max
- BeQuiet Straight Power 11 850W

Comment: Have you tried to run some benchmarks?

Comment: As I said in the post, benchmarks don't trigger these performance drops, even when maxing out GPU and CPU for extended periods of time.

Comment: Some day I will learn to read. Have you tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sl2LZ6XpUK0

Comment: Have you tried changing directx versions and vsync

Comment: I just tried the CPU usage fix, that does reduce the usage a bit but has no impact on the problem. Also tried directx, vsync, and all other graphics settings and resolutions for that matter. None of that makes any difference, even at lowest settings and 800x640 it still happens just as frequently.

Comment: I did however try some more benchmarks, and to my surprise Prime95 actually does cause drops in CPU usage! I don't understand why though, everything looks fine up until 5 minutes into a torture test where the temperature suddenly shoots up by 30 °C in less than a second for no apparent reason.

Comment: sadly the internet is full of people complaining but so far no one has a fix.

Comment: Check perhaps cooling and airways.

Comment: The cooling is fine, I have a pretty beefy CPU cooler and also tested with running the case open. This is not a normal temperature issue, the problem is that the CPU suddenly starts drawing insane amounts of power and heating by 30 degrees in less than a second